# Use Chartjs-Annotation-Plugin without using "import"

Tags: charts, chart.js

Is there a way to use the newest version of the chart-annotation-plugion as an inline plugin?
How I currently do it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.1.0/chart.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@1.0.0-rc/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0-beta.1/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" ></script>
```

But in newer versions of ChartJS you need to register your plugins, but I dont think the plugin has a global property to register it, like the datalabel plugin (https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#installation) has.

Here are the docs for the annotation plugin: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/integration.html.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I don't see a response yet and I was also having trouble figuring it out.

Simply include

```
<script>
Chart.register('chartjs-plugin-annotation');
Chart.register('chartjs-plugin-datalabels');

// ... rest of your code
</script>
```

somewhere near the top of your scripts after your CDN imports.

As per the Chartjs plugin documentation, this will work with any plugin that follows the naming convention `chartjs-plugin-*`

***Edit:**
Adding a working example; credit to @dennis-bauszus for most of the chart layout.*
https://codepen.io/jarrilla/pen/OJjMVEo

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but this cannot possibly work. You cannot register a string value to your global Chart object. Chart.register(ChartDataLabels) could work, or inline registration in the Chart configuration.

Comment: Did you even try it? [https://jsfiddle.net/co5fhps0/](https://jsfiddle.net/co5fhps0/)

Comment: Did you try this with an actual chart? Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/dbauszus-glx/pen/jOLbgMG ; You can quote the chartjs-plugin-annotation in the register. No error. But also no annotation in chart.

Comment: I can upvote if you add a working fiddle or codepen to the provided answer.

Comment: You're using a preprocessor in your example which is not what OP asked about.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jarrilla/pen/OJjMVEo for working example with inlines; as per OP's specification. (Just a copy paste of your code, with inlines & 1 annotation @DennisBauszus )

Comment: Excellent. Can you edit the answer, ie. add the codepen. Otherwise I cannot upvote as this is currently locked.

Comment: The `Chart.register('chartjs-plugin-annotation');` line in the **codepen** example does nothing.  You can comment it out or delete it, and the example still displays the dashed red annotation line.